# System.Management missing for Windows 8.1 target?

Tags: c#, .net

I feel a tad stupid but... I think I just can't find a way to get System.Management on Windows 8.1. What am I missing here? If I create a standard Windows 8.1 project like this:

[image: Windows 8.1 project creation]

I can't use System.Management... and can't find anything that can be added as a reference to get to something similar.

Any Ideas?

Comment: likely thats not supported.

Comment: Well, that much I did imagine, but I can't figure out any alternative either, and that makes very little or no sense to me.